# How can i set color in PieChart of MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, colors, pie-chart, mpandroidchart

I try to set color in PieChart of MPAndroidChart.But its not set it.I want to add custom color in my partition . Here is my code :-

```
fun setupPieChartView() {
    mPie = findViewById(R.id.piechart)

    mPie?.setUsePercentValues(true)

    val desc: Description = Description()
    desc.text = "PieChart"
    mPie?.description = desc

    val legend: Legend? = mPie?.legend
    legend?.horizontalAlignment = Legend.LegendHorizontalAlignment.LEFT

    val value = Arrays.asList(trueAns.toFloat(), wrongAns.toFloat(), noAns.toFloat())
    val label = Arrays.asList("True", "false", "Not")

    val entry = ArrayList<PieEntry>()
    for (i in value.indices) {
        entry.add(PieEntry(value.get(i), label.get(i)))

    }


    val dataSet = PieDataSet(entry, "Result")
    dataSet.setDrawValues(true)

    val pieData = PieData(dataSet)
    pieData.setValueFormatter(PercentFormatter())
    pieData.setValueTextSize(10f)
    pieData.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE)

    mPie?.data = pieData
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this

```
dataSet.colors = ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS.toList()
```

it should be

```
dataSet.setColors(Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE);
```

Because first one gives default colors, that's why you can't override colors. Here is result of your code :

[image]

Comment: thanks but when My data like that True = 1 , False = 3, Not  = 96 , my data not set properlly in Pie chart , How can i manage it?

Comment: Ok , but it is another question. It is not proper to edit question and put absolutely new one instead of original.
Please put back initial question, because my answer looks very silly and not relevant. Open another question and copy here link, I will try to help with that one also.

Comment: Thanks, paste here link of new question whe you create, I will try to help :)

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51493521/manage-text-in-some-situation-piechart-of-mpandroidchart] Here is the link @Misha