# manage text in some Situation PieChart of MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, text, kotlin, pie-chart, mpandroidchart

I try to manage text in PieChart of MPAndroidChart. But when my text is difficult situation like True = 2, False = 3 , Not = 95, in this situation my pie chart layout is very bad.
Here is my code :-

```
fun setupPieChartView() {
    mPie = findViewById(R.id.piechart)

    mPie?.setUsePercentValues(true)

    val desc: Description = Description()
    desc.text = "PieChart"
    mPie?.description = desc

    val legend: Legend? = mPie?.legend
    legend?.horizontalAlignment = Legend.LegendHorizontalAlignment.LEFT

    val value = Arrays.asList(trueAns.toFloat(), wrongAns.toFloat(), noAns.toFloat())
    val label = Arrays.asList("True", "false", "Not")

    val entry = ArrayList<PieEntry>()
    for (i in value.indices) {
        entry.add(PieEntry(value.get(i), label.get(i)))

    }


    val dataSet = PieDataSet(entry, "Result")
    dataSet.setColors(Color.GREEN, Color.RED, Color.GRAY);
    dataSet.setDrawValues(true)

    val pieData = PieData(dataSet)
    pieData.setValueFormatter(PercentFormatter())
    pieData.setValueTextSize(10f)
    pieData.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE)

    mPie?.data = pieData
}
```

Result is like that :-

[image]

here in my Pie-Chart data is not set in good format . Help me for this

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need this line, so your labels will be outside graph:

```
dataSet.setYValuePosition(PieDataSet.ValuePosition.OUTSIDE_SLICE);
```

And value will be outside . You can also control position, line length and coloring like this:

```
    pieData.setValueTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    dataSet.setValueLinePart1OffsetPercentage(10.f);
    dataSet.setValueLinePart1Length(0.43f);
    dataSet.setValueLinePart2Length(.1f);
    dataSet.setValueTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    dataSet.setXValuePosition(PieDataSet.ValuePosition.OUTSIDE_SLICE);
    mPie.setEntryLabelColor(Color.BLUE);
```

Here is result:

[image]